# Actions not passing to the reducres from saga in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

When I login into the user, it has success response, but the action is not passed to the reducer. But while registering a user, it's working fine.

```
//saga.js
import { put, takeEvery, all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {getRequest, postRequest} from '../../helpers/axiosClient';
import actions from "./actions";

function* registerUserAsync(params) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(() => postRequest('users/register', params.payload));
        yield put({
            type: actions.ON_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: response.data,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        yield put({
            type: actions.ON_REGISTER_FAILURE,
            payload: "Something Went Wrong",
        });
    }
}
function* loginUserAsync(params){
    try {
        const response = yield call(() => postRequest('users/login', params.payload));
        yield put({
            type: actions.ON_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        })
        } catch (error) {
        yield put({
            type: actions.ON_LOGIN_FAILURE,
            payload:error.response.data.message
        })
        }}
function* forgetPasswordUser(params){
    try {
        const response = yield call(() => getRequest(`users/restorepassword/${params.payload}`));
        yield put({
                type: actions.ON_PASSWORD_RECOVERY_SUCCESS,
                payload: "PASSWORD RECOVER",
            });
        } catch (error) {
        }}
function* registerUser() {
    yield takeEvery('ON_REGISTER', registerUserAsync)
}
function* loginUser(){
    yield takeEvery('ON_LOGIN', loginUserAsync)
}
function* forgetPassword(){
    yield takeEvery('ON_FORGET_PASSWORD',forgetPasswordUser )
}
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        registerUser(),
        loginUser(),
        forgetPassword()
    ])
}
```

actions.js

```
const actions={
    ON_REGISTER: "ON_REGISTER",
    ON_REGISTER_SUCCESS: "ON_REGISTER_SUCCESS",
    ON_REGISTER_FAILURE: "ON_REGISTER_FAILURE",
    ON_LOGIN: "ON_LOGIN",
    ON_LOGIN_SUCCESS: "ON_LOGIN_SUCCESS",
    ON_LOGIN_FAILURE: "ON_LOGIN_FAILURE",
    ON_PASSWORD_RECOVERY_SUCCESS: "ON_PASSWORD_RECOVERY_SUCCESS",
    ON_FORGET_PASSWORD:"ON_FORGET_PASSWORD",

}
export default actions;
```

reducer.js

```
import actions from "./actions";
const stateInit={
    registerUser: {
        first_name:"",
        last_name: "",
        email: "",
        password:"",
        confirm_password:"",
    },
    loadRegister:false,
    signedUp:false,
    loginUser: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },

}
export default function auth(state=stateInit, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case actions.ON_REGISTER:{
            return {
                ...state,
                registerUser: action.payload,
                loadRegister: true
            }
        }
        case actions.ON_REGISTER_SUCCESS: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loginUser: action.payload,
                loadRegister: false,
                signedUp: true,
            }
        }
        case actions.ON_REGISTER_FAILURE:{
            alert(action.payload)
            return {
                ...state,
                loadRegister: false,
                signedUp :false,
            }
        }
        case action.ON_LOGIN :{
            alert("on login")
            return {
                ...state,
            }
        }
        case action.ON_LOGIN_SUCCESS:{
            alert("ogin suceess")
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }

        case action.ON_LOGIN_FAILURE :{
            return {
                ...state,
            }
        }
        case action.ON_FORGET_PASSWORD: {
            alert("FORGET password")
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
        case action.ON_PASSWORD_RECOVERY_SUCCESS:{
            alert("password recovered")
        }
        default:{
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have the code, which I have. the same structure which for login as in the register, but when I have success response it dies not go to that actions.

Comment: Everything seems OK at first glance. What debugging have you done? I'd add something like [redux-logger](https://github.com/LogRocket/redux-logger) (or just add some `console.log`s in the `auth` reducer and `loginUserAsync` saga) and follow the request - does the network call succeed? Is the saga called? Does the reducer get the action? and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small typo in your switch statement. All the actions with their types should be **actions**.TYPE

For the case of login, you put **action**.ON_LOGIN instead of **actions**.ON_LOGIN